# LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file "default.profraw": Operation not permitted used Monkey

Tags: ios, jailbreak

When i use MonkeyDev debug other app in appStore, I meet this error message.

> systerm:xcode9-beta device:iOS9.3.2

Comment: https://github.com/AloneMonkey/MonkeyDev/issues/68  Also this is not actually LLVM related

Answer (score 0):

Comment out `rebind_symbols((struct rebinding[1]){{"sysctl", my_sysctl, (void*)&orig_sysctl}},1);` in `AntiAntiDebugging.m` , as pointed out by https://github.com/AloneMonkey/MonkeyDev/issues/68